# JavaScript calendar dont show the first of month if is sunday

Tags: javascript, calendar

I am using the following Javascript calendar. The problem is that if the first day of the month is a Sunday, it won't show up. See August.

The script has already been adapted by a friend to allow the week to start on Mondays. I appreciate any help, thank you very much!

```
function getDays(passedInDate, date, i, local) {
var month = {
    name: date.toLocaleString(local, { month: 'long'}),
    year: date.getFullYear(),
    weeks: []
};
var newDate = new Date(passedInDate.getFullYear(), passedInDate.getMonth() + i, 1).getMonth();
var counter = 0;
while (date.getMonth() === newDate) {
    var week = getNumberOfWeeks(newDateInstance(date));
    //if(week == 5)
    //    break;
    if (typeof month.weeks[week] === 'undefined') {
        month.weeks[week] = {};
    }

    var day = newDateInstance(date);

    day.setTime(day.getTime() + (24 * 3600 * 1000));
    //console.log(day);

    if(week == 0 && counter == 0 && day.getDay() >= 2){
        
        var tempDay = new Date(day.getTime() - (24 * 3600 * 1000));
    
        month.weeks[week][tempDay.getDay()-1] = {
            date: tempDay
        };
    }
    else if(week == 0 && counter == 0 && day.getDay() == 0){
        console.log(day.getDay());
        var tempDay = new Date(day.getTime() - (24 * 3600 * 1000));
        
        month.weeks[week][5] = {
            date: tempDay
        };
    }
    
    if(week == 4 && day.getDate() == 1 || week == 5 && day.getDate() == 1){
        break;
    }    
    if(day.getDay() == 0){
        month.weeks[week][6] = {
            date: day
        };
    }else{
        month.weeks[week][day.getDay()-1] = {
            date: day
        };    
    }
    
    
    date.setDate(date.getDate() +1);

    counter++;
}
return month;
}
```

[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yn37Luem/)

Comment: In the My fiddle, maybe :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function is way overcomplicated than needed:

```
function getNumberOfWeeks(date) {
    let w = date.getDay() - 1;
    if (w < 0)
        w = 6;

    return Math.ceil((date.getDate() - 1 - w) / 7);
}

function getDays(passedInDate, date, i, local) {
    const newDate = new Date(passedInDate.getFullYear(), passedInDate.getMonth() + i, 1).getMonth(),
          month = {
              name: date.toLocaleString(local, { month: 'long'}),
              year: date.getFullYear(),
              weeks: []
          };

    while (date.getMonth() === newDate) {

        const _date = newDateInstance(date),
              week = getNumberOfWeeks(_date),
              day = _date.getDay();

        if (month.weeks[week] === undefined) {
            month.weeks[week] = {};
        }
        month.weeks[week][day ? day - 1 : 6] = {
          date: _date
        };    

        date.setDate(date.getDate() +1);
    }
    return month;
}
```

Also, `month.weeks[week][day]` contains unnecessary `{date: Date}` object, it could simply contain `Date` by itself (there are 2 placed that would need be adopted for that by  removing `.date`)

Side note:
Please avoid unnecessary calls to same functions, call them once and store the result in a variable, than use the variable instead. Just count how many times `day.getDay()` was executed...ouch!

Comment: Thank you, but now the days are displayed incorrectly (August, September) [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b698nw5j/)